# Por que o logback usa tanto logback-test.xml como logback.xml como nome do arquivo de configuração?

Tags: java, logback

Lendo o manual do logback, na [seção de configuração](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration), ele fala que procura pelos seguintes arquivos de configuração, em ordem:

1. logback-test.xml
2. logback.groovy
3. logback.xml

Qual o motivo de haver o sufixo `-test`? Pra mim só havendo logback.xml faz sentido. Pra que enlongar o nome do arquivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testes de unidade normalmente incluem o projeto inteiro no classpath, inclusive arquivos de configuração, dentre eles o `logback.xml`.

Ocorre que as configurações de log dos testes de unidade normalmente são diferentes da configuração de log do projeto para produção. Uma forma simples de se resolver isso é colocar o arquivo `logback-test.xml` no classpath dos testes de unidade. Assim, o Logback saberá quando escolher o arquivo de configuração correto e o nome deixará claro se você está usando o de produção (`logback.xml`) ou o de teste (`logback-test.xml`).